# Can mysql replication be configured to prevent drop database being replicated?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Can mysql replication be configured to prevent certain commands being replicated to the slaves.

Imagine a completely invented scenario where someone types

```
drop database foo;
```

into the wrong ssh window
(I know, it can never happen)

Currently mysql will replicate that command to the slaves.

Can you block that and so redirect the application server to use on of the slaves and keep systems running.

I fully understand that this question is only one dimension of a DR strategy.

We run mysql 5.5

Answer (score 0):

replicate just one database and do not grant drop database to the user on slave server

```
replicate-do-db=db01
```

or replicate table per table:

```
replicate-do-table=db_name.tbl_name
```

sorry the poor english

Comment: thanks for the reply, now add in the problem that the user is the admin on the mysql box...

Comment: I don't know how help with that... I just can imagine some sort of trigger with incrond to read an DELETE on database directory and start a recover from the last snapshot of the file system...

Comment: I know, years old. but in case someone is looking for ideas: what about delays? you could delay for 15 minutes and then stop slave the moment you realise something is wrong.